Why do lambdas called after re-composition?
I use MVI architecture in my app.
I have a Navigation composable, which handles the navigation related stuff.
I noticed that, when the screen changes (backStackEntry) changed, all of the lambdas are re run for some reason, which cause a bug in my app.
Right now, when I open the PlantDetail screen, the onNavigatedToDetailScreen()  is called, which is good, but if I navigate back, the function and the others are also called again.
Here is a part of my Navigation class:
@OptIn(ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class)
@Composable
fun Navigation(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController,
    isUserLoggedIn: Boolean,
    onBackPressed: () -> Unit = {},
    saveUserLoggedInData: (UserData) -> Unit = {},
    onNavigatedToDetailScreen: () -> Unit
) {
    val startDestination = if (isUserLoggedIn) Screens.Main.Home else Screens.Auth.Login

    SharedTransitionLayout {
        NavHost(
            modifier = modifier, navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination
        ) {
            mainGraph(
                onBackPressed,
                navigateToDetailScreen = {
                    navController.navigate(Screens.Main.PlantDetail(it))
                },
                sharedTransitionScope = this@SharedTransitionLayout,
                onNavigatedToDetailScreen = onNavigatedToDetailScreen
            )

            authGraph(saveUserLoggedInData)
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class)
fun NavGraphBuilder.mainGraph(
    onBackPressed: () -> Unit = {},
    sharedTransitionScope: SharedTransitionScope,
    navigateToDetailScreen: (String) -> Unit,
    onNavigatedToDetailScreen: () -> Unit
) {
    sharedTransitionScope.apply {
        composable<Screens.Main.Home> {
            BackHandler {
                onBackPressed()
            }

            HomeScreenMain(
                navigateToDetailScreen = navigateToDetailScreen, animatedVisibilityScope = this
            )
        }

        composable<Screens.Main.PlantDetail> { backStackEntry ->
            onNavigatedToDetailScreen()
            val plantId = backStackEntry.toRoute<Screens.Main.PlantDetail>().id

            PlantDetail(
                plantId = plantId, animatedVisibilityScope = this
            )
        }
    }
}


I sure it is caused by the re-composition, but I don't know, which is the proper way to handle it.

I figured out.
Part of the issue was caused by this: bug?, and the other part was caused by me.
When I navigate to somewhere and back, re-compositon happens couple of times, then the Navigation composable re run. I called the onNavigatedToDetailScreen()  in the wrong way, so basically it is triggered every time.
To resolve it, I moved every related logic inside a LaunchedEffect, which listens to the route.
LaunchedEffect(key1 = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route) {
                    viewModel.setEvent(MainActivityState.Event.OnScreenChanged(navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route))
                }

